# $f:(2,4)→(1,3)$ where $f(x)=x-[x/2]$ (where $[.]$ is the greatest integer function/floor function),then what will be $f^{-1}(x)$.

Tags: functions

Let $f:(2,4)→(1,3)$ where $f(x)=x-[x/2]$ (where $[.]$ is the greatest integer function/floor function),then what will be $f^{-1}(x)$?
I can't understand how to manipulate the floor function.Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For $x \in (2, 4)$, we have $\lfloor x/2\rfloor = 1$.

Comment: Oh I wonder why I did'nt spot it.Thanks a ton :-)